# MySQL Multiple Where Conditions, Results Do Not Meet All Conditions

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, where-clause, between

I have a query that is being injected to MySQL from expressJS, however when these queries are executed. At times I am returned data that does not meet the conditions correctly.

---

**Original:**

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE status = 'Invoiced'
  AND (ordereddate between '2009-12-01' AND '2011-12-30')
  OR (duedate between '2009-12-01' AND '2011-12-30');
```

**Results:**

```
Ordered Date   Due Date      Status
2009-11-18     2009-12-16    Invoiced
2009-11-18     2009-12-14    Cancelled
```

The results show items with any status is being pulled, but the date condition is met.

---

**Tried:**

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE (status = 'Invoiced')
  AND (ordereddate between '2009-12-01' AND '2011-12-30')
  AND (duedate between '2009-12-01' AND '2011-12-30');
```

**Results:**
If either the `ordereddate` or the `duedate` are out of the date range, the item will be left out of the result.

Changed to `AND` instead of `OR`

---

**Tried:**

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE status = 'Invoiced'
  AND (ordereddate AND duedate between '2009-12-01' AND '2011-12-30');
```

**Results:**
Returns everything correctly, except if either the `ordereddate` or the `duedate` are out of the date range, the row will be left out of the result.

Combined `ordereddate` and `duedate` where condition

---

**Tried:**

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE status = 'Invoiced'
  AND (ordereddate OR duedate between '2009-12-01' AND '2011-12-30');
```

**Result:**

```
Ordered Date   Due Date      Status
2008-07-07     2008-07-28    Invoiced
2008-07-07     2008-07-25    Invoiced
2008-07-07     2008-07-23    Invoiced
```

This one appears to pull the correct status, however the date is incorrect, it appears to be pulling anything with the status Invoiced, and ignoring the date range.

Comment: Your last two expressions involve `x AND ...` and `x OR ...` -- in each of these cases `x` is tested for true/false (non-zero/zero) to come up with a value.  That is, it is really not what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to use additional brackets:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    status = 'Invoiced'
    AND (
           (ordereddate between '2009-12-01' AND '2011-12-30')
        OR (duedate between '2009-12-01' AND '2011-12-30')
    )
;
```

Comment: Awesome! This was exactly it! It is working as intended now. I would upvote the answer, but I do not have enough rep. Thank you again!

Comment: @AndrewBaker I believe you should be able to 'accept' the answer :)

Comment: This is because `AND` has 'precedence' over `OR`, and the attempt was effectively `(x AND y) OR z` when you wanted `x AND (y OR z)`.